# How to find the number of positive values in a vector in R studio?

Tags: r, vector, count

I am working with a large vector of about 3000 entries, and want to know how many of those entries are positive values. I'm not sure what function/code to use to determine this.

Comment: `sum(x > 0)` where `x` is your vector

Answer (score 2):

Take a sum of boolean after checking which values are greater than `0`. The reason this works is because `TRUE` will be coerced to `1` and `FALSE` will be coerced to `0`

```
x = -10:10
sum(x > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your vector is named as `v`:

```
# To see how many of them are positive
sum(v > 0)

# Indexing the ones that are positive
v[v > 0]
```